# How Can I generate radio buttons based on the number of quiz questions I have?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm just starting out with php and wanted to do a fun project to get better with it. I created a text file that starts with the question, then has the answer choices, and then has the answer index:

```
What does charmander evolve to?#Charmeleon:charizard:squirtle#0
Who is the main character in Pokemon?#Misty:Ash:Brock#1
```

How can I generate radio buttons based on the number of questions there are?

```
<?php
    $quizStuff = file("quiz1.txt");

        foreach ($quizStuff as $questions) {
            $questionParse = explode("#", $question);
            $answerChoices = explode(":",$questionParse[1]);
            echo "$questionParse[0] ? <br />";


            foreach ($answerChoices as $answerChoice) {
                # create radio button and print answer choice next to it
            }
        }
?>
```

Since radio buttons are a type of form, I was thinking that I would have a submit button at the end of the question and the next question would pop up after a user pressed submit. General design input would be great too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not used to making text file as a database but here is what i see a solution. I put a counter to identify which question is where the choices are included.

```
$ctr = 1;
    foreach ($quizStuff as $questions) {
         $questionParse = explode("#", $question);
         $answerChoices = explode(":",$questionParse[1]);
         echo "$questionParse[0] ? <br />";


         foreach ($answerChoices as $answerChoice) {
             echo "<input type='radio' id='".$answerChoice.$ctr."' name='question$ctr' value='$answerChoice'> <label for='".$answerChoice.$ctr."'>".$answerChoice."</label><br>"
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this works to mostly! The radio buttons is being generated but it isn't showing the answer choice next to it

Comment: Sorry i forgot. I edited my post and added a label containing the choice

Comment: Hey another quick question! I have a submit button after the loop that runs the same php script again but with a different question. I can't figure out how to get which radio button the user selected however. Any ideas?